# Using regular expression in SQL to read the values for an attribute

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on Snowflake to look for values for a string in a particular field. For example, I have a column called `col1` with two values as follows

```
1. |LFD: |**Wed 07 Jul 2021**|
2. LFD & additional info
```

Here in the first record we have value for string `LFD`, given as July 7,2021. But in second row we don't have value for LFD.

I tried to create a boolean flag as follows;

```
case when col1 ilike '%LFD%' then 0 else 1 end as LFD_missing_flag
```

Interestingly it is giving 0 for both rows, but it shd be giving 1 for second row and 0 for first row.
**Expected Output**

```
    col1                              LFD_missing_flag
  |LFD: |**Wed 07 Jul 2021**|   |      0
             
   LFD & additional info.       |      1
```

Since in second row we don't have value for LFD, it shd be 1, otherwise 0, as seen for first record.

**Modifications**
Along the same lines I have following piece of text;

```
|FIRMS Code: |**Unknown**|
|FIRMS Code: |**WAM7**|
|FIRMS Code: |WAM7|
```

For this case the output shd be;

```
col1                           FIRMS_flag
|FIRMS Code: |**Unknown**|        1
|FIRMS Code: |**WAM7**|.          0
|FIRMS Code: |WAM7|.              0
```

Can I get help to modify my logic so that I can get the correct output? thanks

Comment: In the 2nd line you have `LFD & Something`. What criteria did you apply to conclude that `& Something` is ***not*** a value?

Comment: given both string have the sub string `LFD` present in them (as you have written it)
you will have to search for more values, OR clean-up you demo data more.

Answer (score 0):

So given both input strings appear to have the sub-string `LFD` in them search for just that is not enough, the row to want result does have a `:` also so we can add that:

```
SELECT 
    column1
    ,column1 ilike '%lfd%' as _like
    ,column1 ilike '%lfd:%' as not_like
    ,(column1 not ilike '%lfd:%')::int as results_a
    ,iff(column1 ilike '%lfd:%', 0, 1) as results_b
    ,case when column1 ilike '%LFD:%' then 0 else 1 end as results_c
FROM VALUES
    ('|LFD: |**Wed 07 Jul 2021**|'),
    ('LFD & additional info')
```

which gives:

| COLUMN1 | _LIKE | NOT_LIKE | RESULTS_A | RESULTS_B | RESULTS_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| |LFD: |**Wed 07 Jul 2021**| | TRUE | TRUE | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| LFD & additional info | TRUE | FALSE | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is it possible to use similar logic for the modifications I have in my question. plz see edits above.